# Bash: How do I properly quote the results of a command

Tags: bash, shell, escaping

My problem boils down to this:

```
echo $(echo '*')
```

That outputs the names of all the files in the current directory.
I do not want that. I want a literal asterisk (`*`).

How do I do this in a generic way?

My above example is simplified. The asterisk is not literally written in my bash script - it comes from the result of another command.

So this is perhaps closer to my real situation:

```
echo $(my-special-command)
```

I just want to get the literal output of `my-special-command`; I do *not* want any embedded asterisks (or other special characters) to be expanded.

How do I do this in a general-purpose way?

I suppose I could do `set -f` before running the command, but how can I be sure that covers everything? That turns off pathname expansion, but what about other kinds? I have zero control over what output might be produced by `my-special-command`, so must be able to handle everything properly.

Comment: Like this?: `echo "$(echo '*')"`

Comment: @j.a. Thanks, that's it! Brain not working today.  If you make an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just enclose the [Command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) with double quotes:

```
echo "$(my-special-command)"
```

Comment: @jwd, It makes even more sense when you assign the result: `result=$(mycmd); echo "$result"` -- you always quote variables, right?

Answer (score 1):

Its called [globbing](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html), you have multiply ways to prevent it:

```
echo * # will expand to files / directories
echo "*" # Will print *
echo '*' # Will also print *
```

In your example you can simple write:

```
echo "$(echo '*')"
```

You can also turn off globbing in your script by calling it with `bash -f script.sh` or inside your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -f
echo *
```

Answer (score 1):

From the "Command Substitution" section of the man page:

> If the [command] substitution appears within double quotes,  word  splitting  and
>          pathname expansion are not performed on the results.

By quoting the command expansion, you prevent its result, `*`, from undergoing pathname expansion.

```
$ echo "$(echo "*")"
```